# VueJS 2 input filter groups

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I have an input:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="filter by country name" />
```

And a list of lists:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="continent in continents">
    {{ continent[0].continent }}
    <ul>
      <li v-for="country of continent">
          {{ country.name }} ({{ country.callingCodes[0]}})
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Which is a list of continents and each one is a list of countries in it.
How do I implement search input to show only countries I'm looking for?
I tried to display a list of filtered countries but then the app displays them in each continent rather than in just appropriate one.

Comment: Can you share glimpse of your json data here?

Comment: This is the exact response => https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all
i've already grouped it using lodash (by subregion)
And you can place 'subregion' instead of 'continent' in the code above

Comment: https://codepen.io/blakewatson/pen/xEXApK - This will give you an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to grab the string from the input field and use it as your search query. This is done by the `v-model` directive, which keeps the view and data in sync.

So, in your template:

```
<input type="search" v-model="query">
```

And the model:

```
data() {
  return {
    query: '',
    countryList: [], // empty while data arrives
  }
}
```

When we load the data, we're gonna keep the original list. We're not doing anything with it yet. We'll group it later, while we also filter it.

```
xhr.onload = function() {
  self.countryList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
};
```

Now, the continents you want to display are not just `_.groupBy`'d anymore -- instead, they are also filtered. Furthermore, this filtering needs to happen whenever `query` changes, too. A perfect candidate for [a computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).

```
computed: {
  continents() {
    const filtered = this.countryList.filter(({name}) => {
      return name.toLowerCase().includes(this.query.toLowerCase())
    });
    return _.groupBy(filtered, "subregion");
  },
},
```

Now we just need to loop over this computed property `continents`.

```
<li v-for="subregion in continents">
    {{ subregion[0].subregion }}
    <ul>
      <li v-for="country of subregion">
          {{ country.name }} ({{ country.callingCodes[0]}})</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it the same as using:
data {
  query: '',
}
?
Because it dosn't do anything. What is the appropriate html for that?

Comment: As far as I know, [`data` must be a function](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't do anything"? If you do a `{{ query }}` next to the `input` field, you should see data change while you type. This is covered in the [very introduction](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Handling-User-Input) of Vue.

Comment: In the same introduction example you provided, data is an object

Comment: Yes, because it's an introduction and it technically works. But the reason is explained later on. It works, but if you have multiple instances of the same component, they will share data, which is probably not what you're after.

Comment: What I mean by doesn't do anything is it doesn't render filtered countries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152960/discussion-between-lazar-ljubenovic-and-adam-marczyk).

Comment: For a root Vue, data can be an object. For a *component* data must be a function. This is the discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks @Bert! Always used only components as Single File Components with webpack.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you might do this.

Basically, bind your filter to a value in data, and return your grouped list based off a computed value.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    countries: null,
    countryFilter: null
  },
  computed: {
    continents() {
      let filteredCountries = this.countries
      let filter = c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.countryFilter.toLowerCase())

      if (this.countryFilter)
        filteredCountries = this.countries.filter(filter)

      return _.groupBy(filteredCountries, "subregion")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then(response => this.countries = response.data)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="countryFilter" type="text" placeholder="filter by country name" />
  <ul>
    <li v-for="continent, name in continents">
      {{name}}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="country in continent">{{country.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Typically with Vue, when performing manipulations on data that you need to be reactive, you will do it with a computed property.